# PlotLabel with Graphics

Tags: graphics, manipulate

Wondering why my PlotLabel does not show up?

```
Clear[s, t]
s[t_] = 189 - 48 t - 11 t^2 + 2 t^3;
v[t_] = s'[t];
a[t_] = s''[t];
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Arrowheads[{-0.02, 0.02}],
   Arrow[{{s[-6], 0}, {s[10], 0}}],
   Red, PointSize[Large],
   Point[{s[t], 0}],
   PlotLabel -> StringForm["Velocity = ``", v[t]]
   }], {{t, -5}, -6, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: It must be `Graphics[{...}, options]`, not `Graphics[{..., options}]`.  `PlotLabel` is an option.

Comment: @Szabolics Perfect! Thanks.